# Updating Pre-release dependencies using nuget

Tags: nuget, versioning

I'm currently develop a set of libraries that progressively add more features.

For example, in my solution, I have a `Foo` project which defines some basic feature set, an additional project, `Foo.Web`, for web specific implementations and `Foo.Web.Tokens` for even more specific features. `Foo.Web.Tokens` depends on `Foo.Web` which depends on `Foo`.

I'm attempting to build separate nuget projects so a user only needs to reference those dependencies they need. I'm versioning the assemblies with GitVersionTask, so after build, they all get the same version number and I'm using the replacement tokens for nuget when building [from a project](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Creating-Packages/Creating-and-Publishing-a-Package#From_a_project) so that the nuget packages all have the same version number.

My problem is that when I try reference a prerelease version of either `Foo.Web` or `Foo.Web.Tokens` nuget is unable to resolve the dependency on `Foo`. If, for example, I have published a `1.1.0.0-alhpa0001` package for each of the assemblies, when I try and update `Foo.Web`, nuget shows this error:

`Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependency 'Foo (≥ 1.1.0.0)'.`

Using the `-Pre` argument doesn't change this. A `Foo.1.1.0-alpha0001.nupkg` does exist but I feel like nuget won't resolve it because it's not a stable version, and I'm letting nuget automatically detect the dependencies from the solution using the following command:

`.\.nuget\NuGet.exe pack source/Foo.Web/Foo.Web.csproj -Build -Version 1.1.0.0-alpha0001 -symbols -IncludeReferencedProjects`

How do I properly allow the `Foo.Web` prerelease package reference the `Foo` prerelease package of the same version?

Comment: I was wondering if you solved this issue? If you did, I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

The `IncludeReferencedProjects` option seems to pull the version from the assemblyinfo.cs of the referenced project.

setting the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` attribute to the desired nuget package version seems to work as you want it to.

eg
`[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.1.0-alpha0001")]`